# asking about the cookie after logout

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to access a cookie's value (using `$_COOKIE`) immediately after calling the `setcookie()` function in PHP. When I do so, `$_COOKIE[$cookiename]` isn't set after login. Why?

```
if(isset($_SESSION)){
    $_SESSION['email']=$username;
    $_SESSION['id']=$query['id'];
    $_SESSION['name']=$query['name'];
    $_COOKIE[$cookiename]=$query['name'];


    $cookiename="user";
    $cookie_value = "John Doe";
    setcookie($cookiename,$cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30),"/");
    if (!$session->Check()){
        echo $cookiename ;
    }else {
        echo $_COOKIE[$cookiename];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is because when you call `setcookie()` you are attaching the cookie to the current response(when the current request completes).
2. $_COOKIE will have a value when a request is made with the cookie header already set i.e cookie is sent to the server.

So, when only #1 happens you don't have anything in $_COOKIE, but once #2 happens you will have a value in $_COOKIE

EDIT: Almost everything you need is mentioned in the manual 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on
>   the next page load with the $_COOKIE array. Cookie values may also
>   exist in $_REQUEST.

Comment: /*now used it but not working..*/$cookie_name="praveen_cookie";
     $cookie_value=$query['name'];
     setcookie($cookie_name,$cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30),"/");